# How I can replace default calendar of Android OS?

Tags: java, android, calendar

Is there any official or non-official API or a hack to replace default calendar (Georgian calendar) of Android OS with another calendar (my own Calendar)? You can see list of calendars around the world [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aSpecific_calendars) if you are not familiar with them.

May I must override [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) or [GregorianCalendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) or [Calendar.getInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28%29)?

*(Added on an edit)* And will it override use of Gregorian calendar totally, for example on Android lock-screen?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is not possible. My original concern was about the lock screen calendar that seems now is possible put a new widget for another calendar type on Android 4.2 so I've lost my interest to find solution of this problem (while I think it must be possible somehow...)!

Now I think the only real solution is patching AOSP itself to use other calendars in the GUI that is of-course not related to this question.

**Edit:**

[Xposed framework](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial) is my dream that came true! Theoretically it can replace any method on Android framework with anything you want. But currently it is not compatible with Android 4.4 per [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=47771876) ([snapshot as 11/28/2013](http://archive.is/LVdYK)) that I hope fixed soon.

Answer (score 4):

`Calendar.getInstance()` is not the Android API. It is standard Java API. `Calendar.getInstance()` calls `createCalendar()` with default time zone and locale. There are factory methods `getInstance()` that accept time zone, locale and both. This is the way to affect the calendar created.

For example as far as I know sending Japanese locale cause creation instance of `JapaneseImperialCalendar`.

EDIT

There are a couple of predefined calendars: `BuddistCalendar` and  Japanese calendar. And obviously default `GregorianCalendar`. You can add you own "extension" using `Locale.setExtension(char key, String value)`. I have never done it but it should work. You should however dig into the code your self to find out the correct parameters. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer :) If you look at Android source Calendar.java, in contrast of JDK source of Calendar (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Calendar.java), you can not find createCalendar() on it. this is source of the related part on it: public static synchronized Calendar getInstance() { return new GregorianCalendar(); }

Comment: @EbrahimByagowi: "overriding this method (by some hackerish way) will affect all use of calendars in Android UI" -- oh `$DEITY` no. You have no right, from an SDK application, to affect other applications in this fashion, for obvious security reasons. You are welcome to fork Android, change the operating system, convert it into a modded ROM, and install that on the device of your choice, if you wish to affect all applications.

Comment: @EbrahimByagowi CommonsWare is 100% correct (as always).  If what you want is to inject some of your code in such a way that whenever any app on the device creates a calendar, they run your code to create the calendar instead of the default, then what you are describing is pretty much how viruses work.  Yours is obviously not malicious, but not what the framework is there to provide.  You only get to write code that works in your area, or you write the framework (create your own version of Android).  Maybe if you elaborated on why you want all calendars to be your calendar, we could help more?

Comment: @xbakesx: I know you, you and commonsware are talking about standard and clean ways to create a simple application like this one that I created (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.byagowi.persiancalendar). But this is not enough for users, for example lock-screen is using Gregorian Calendar. I want to replace that (and other places are using calendar) with my calendar (and of-course I know this is possible with making a Custom ROM from scratch) and as you may know, in iOS, Gregorian Calendar is not the only calendar available (and you can put Persian Calendar as default)

Comment: May stackoverflow is not suitable for such this question and xda-developers is better place. I really don't care if I couldn't do this without root permission or terminal scripting. I just want do more localization for Android environment without making a new ROM and I think this is not really impossible! :) Thanks

Comment: [Xposed](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial), actually this was what I want to find.